# Python exceptions and parsing of complex data

Tags: python, parsing, exception

Let's say I have some isolated Python code that processes data produced by some other entity (E.g. a client).

The data I receive may be in incorrect form (e.g. due to client's sloppiness, data corruption, you name it), so that processing in my Python code will somehow fail, and that will lead to some exception being raised. Let's assume that the code downstream is just interested in knowing if processing was correct and wrong, and not *why* it was wrong.

My concern is the following: what is the best practice for raising such exception on a *complex* bad input? How to organize the exceptions in this case?

Data can turn out to be incorrect in a lot of ways, especially if the correct formatting of the data is complex. In some cases I may easily catch the error myself (e.g. if I find an incorrect magic value, in which case I may raise my `FancyCustomizedException`), but in others some generic exception could get raised as well (e.g. some `ValueException`).

Is it OK to say that processing was wrong if *any* exception is raised (in which case the code downstream will use very a generic (and ugly) `try: ... except: ...`)?

Is it better to catch **all** generic exceptions and hide them inside my `FancyCustomizedException` (in which case the code downstream will use very a less generic `try: ... except FancyCustomizedException, e: ...`, but I will litter *my* code with `try: ... except: ...`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to have a need for quite some validation I would simply wrap all validation 'errors' on a given input in a *ValidationSummary* object / instance (which contains a list of everything which went wrong) and pass that around instead.

On a more general note: contrary to other languages, structuring program flow by exception handling is common and accepted in Python. A Python idiom related to this is called EAFP (It's Easier to ask forgiveness then permission).

Comment: Could you point me to any open source project doing that technique?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO is better to create you own exception hierarchy, and throws concrete exceptions in every situation, for example, a BaseValidationException, for generic validation exceptions, like ValueXException, etc.. other hierarchy for custom exceptions, etc.. then, you can catch based on the base or on specific exceptions if you want...

```
ProcessException
  + ValidationException
    + ValueXException
    + LimitYException
  + FancyCustomExceptionA
    + FancyCustomDetailException
  + FancyOtherExtensionB
    ...
```

You can alway filter by ProcessException, or catch especific exceptions...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using exceptions is more reliable than just returning the error codes from functions.  The reason is that testing the returned value makes the code around the calls more unreadable and one tends not to check it.  So, go for exceptions.

If you are not sure, use only the generic exceptions -- i.e. do not create your own exception classes.  You can always add them later.  It is probably better to think more about of what kind the exception should be (the existing one) than to create a lot of new of them.

You can write the code so that it will have the core that complains about everything that goes wrong (via exceptions).  Then you can write a layer that is more forgiving and tries to be *clever* to solve some of the situations.  (However, sometimes the *cleverness* of the software may make the user crazy :)